# HTTPS server variable causing Wordpress to crash without error

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I have been at this for over a day and I have finally found the cause of the issue, but i dont understand what is going on. I have enabled SSL for a website and its working to a degree. The pages are loading fine and quite a few are loading with the green padlock, but some are not. I have found out the cause and its all coming down to the HTTPS key in the `$_SERVER` variable.

I am using Cloudflare and I have installed the plugin to allow for SSL. This is not working for me and causes the website to display a blank white page with no data, no error message and a response code of 200. I looked at the code and found out the problem.

```php
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

I did some messing around and found that even when `$_SERVER['HTTPS']='off'` the issue occurs. The only time that it works is when `isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])` is `false`. When the HTTPS key doesn't exist the site loads.

Without an error message im left in the dark here. Has anyone ever seen this before?

Comment: did you update cloud flare to persistently use SSL, and did you update the wordpress domain conf to https?

Comment: yes i did, but this seems to make the HTTPS variable exist without the need of the plugin. When this exists in the server vars the site will not load

Comment: checked the php error log on the server

Comment: i checked the error log. nothing gets written to it

Comment: Can you turn cloudflare off? I dont think you actually need a plugin, just move your site over to SSL without cloudflare then re-enable afterwards.

Comment: how do you mean turn off? Disable the SSL stuff or completely remove it from the domain and go back to godaddy? I have already tried to disable the caching and it didnt seem to do much

Comment: Just turn off cloudflare from pointing to your site, then get the ssl working.

Comment: i dont think this is the issue though. HTTPS is a common variable with apache. why is the site crashing when its present?